# IOS Simulator behaving correct?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios-simulator

Starting the IOS Simulator for IPhone 6s does appearing the device in portrait mode.
Then when I rotate the device with Hardware->rotate, then the device rotates, but the content not.

Is this the way in behaves in reality ?

I am asking, because I can't test the rotation correctly.
When I start my app, then things which should be centered appearing not in the center. Should content rotation not be managed by IOS. Do we have to care of these things?

[image]

**UPDATE**

Added a new Scrrenshot. 
[image]

Good to know that the Iphone's default screen is not rotating. 
This leads to the following question :
But is the following correct. When the device is in landscape mode, the app (rotable app) starts in portrait and immediatelly rotates to landscape. So we have to handle the rotation change at start of the app ?

Comment: You are opening the settings app of iPhone that is not set as a  rotating app

Comment: I added a new screenshot . This is the default screen. Is this also not rotating ?

Comment: the default screen never rotates for iPhone not even in the device itself.

Comment: If you want to check the rotation simply create an app with rotations , Please check my answer.

Comment: ok. Good to know. But is the following correct. When the device is in landscape mode, the app (rotable app) starts in portrait and immediatelly rotates to landscape. So we have to handle the rotation change at start of the app ?

Comment: If you want an app to start with landscape mode just uncheck the portrait device orientations.

Comment: No no :-) Its not that easy. I like to show the app in any direction and I checked all this checkboxes. The question is. Does it rotate at beginning. When I start my app and the device is in landscape -> The app is started in portrait and then rotates. Is this the way it is behiving in reality ? So this would mean we have to handle an rotation event at start of the app if we have for exemple a centered Picture (Added at runtime with own position). My picture isn't centered actually in landscape mode, because the app starts in portrait and rotates the screen around the leftupper corner.

Comment: You have to handle it with auto layout or you need to handle it programmatically  http://www.raywenderlich.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=37&t=10148  this link can help you.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Please goto project ->targets->General goto Deployment Info section and check Device orientation